# android map items not cleared

Tags: android, android-mapview

I'm repeating the following code every x seconds in my MapActivity:

```
 mapview.invalidate();
 for (int i=0; i<mapview.getOverlays().size(); i++ ) 
 {
     mapview.getOverlays().remove(i);
 }

 mapview.getOverlays().clear();
 List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapview.getOverlays();
 //set new geoponts here and add 2 markers via itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
 mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
 mapview.invalidate();
```

Though I can see on the GUI that it's not refreshing the page, it's always drawing on top of it. It doesn't seem to clear the content before putting new stuff on.

Also using `postinvalidate()` doesn't work

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't mind someone downvoting my question, but could you please also tell me why? Atleast then I know what I do wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference of  `itemizedoverlay` was not in that function, I moved it there and now it works.